# Finding sum of N largest elements of array of single-digit values

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the top 100 numbers from one hundred million of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550624/retrieving-the-top-100-numbers-from-one-hundred-million-of-numbers)

I have  a array which consists  positive number between 0 to 9,(digit can repeat).  I want to find sum of N largest elements

```
For example array =  5 1 2 4 and N=2
ans = 5+4 = 9
```

Simple approach: sort array and find sum of n largest elements.  But i dont want to use it

Comment: I think the limitation that elements are between 0 and 9 makes it not a close duplicate.  There are more efficient answers here that take advantage of the restricted range.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of that other question due to the constraints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest O(n) solution is the following:

1. Run through array `a` and increasе `b[a[i]]` where `b` is a zero initialized array of 10 integers.
2. Run through `b` starting from the end (9<sup>th</sup> position) and if `b[i]` is lower than `N` add `b[i] * i` to your answer, then decrease `N` by `b[i]`, otherwise if `b[i]` is greater or equal to `N` add `N * i` to the answer and over the loop.

**Edit:** *code*

```
vector<int> b(10, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    b[a[i]]++;
}

int sum = 0;
for(int i = 9;  i >= 0; --i) {
    if(b[i] < n) {
        sum += b[i] * i;
        n -= b[i];
    } else {
        sum += n * i;
        n = 0;
        break;
    }
}
if(n != 0) {
    // no enough element in the array
}
```

Comment: +1. my solution didn't take advantage of the fact that all elements are 0-9, so a radix sort (which is O(n)) will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

insert all into a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), and then delete (and sum) N elements. 

complexity: `O(n+Nlogn)`, because creating a heap is O(n), and each delete is O(logn), and you iterate over delete N times. total: O(n+Nlogn) [where n is the number of elements in your array].

**EDIT**: I missed it at first, but all your numbers are digits. so the simplest solution will be using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) or [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) and then sum the N biggest elements. solution is O(n).

Comment: what about inserting in BST and then traversing right root left, and decprementing N each time till i reach 0

Comment: @akshay: inserting into a sort tree requires a sort, which will be O(nlogn), which is worth then O(n+Nlogn)

Comment: @akshay's solution with sorting is better.

Comment: @Mihran: it results in worth performance for N << n (where n is the array's size)

Comment: @amit and Mihran:So can i say that sorting approach is better then BST and bst is better then ur heap method

Comment: @akshay: NO. sorting and BST are equivalent, both are O(nlogn), where heap is O(n+Nlogn), and O(n+Nlogn) is better then O(nlogn) [n is the number of elements in the array]

Comment: @all:can there be any methamathical approach ?BST approach doesnot take advantage of the fact that all nos are between 0 to 9

Comment: @akshay: see my edit and @Mihran's answer, both are taking advantage of the facts that all elements are integers in the range [0,9]

Comment: wht is array is already sorted?in this case will time complexity will be O(n)??? or O(n2) [ n square]

Comment: @akshay: if the array is already sorted, you just need to summarize N elements, it will be O(N), since N<=n it is indeed O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit slow today, should code faster hehe ;-)

There are multiple answers already but I want to share my pseudo-code with you anyway, hope it helps!

```
public class LargestSumAlgorithm
{
    private ArrayList arValues;

    public void AddValueToArray(int p_iValue)
    {
        arValues.Add(p_iValue);
    }

    public int ComputeMaxSum(int p_iNumOfElementsToCompute)
    {
        // check if there are n elements in the array
        int iNumOfItemsInArray = arValues.Size;
        int iComputedValue = 0;

        if(iNumOfItemsInArray >= p_iNumOfElementsToCompute)
        {
            // order the ArrayList ascending - largest values first
            arValues.Sort(SortingEnum.Ascending);
            // iterate over the p_iNumOfElementsToCompute in a zero index based ArrayList
            for(int iPositionInValueArray = 0; iPositionInValueArray < p_iNumOfElementsToCompute); iPositionInValueArray++)
            {
                iComputedValue += arValues[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException;
        }

        return iComputedValue;
    }


    public LargestSumAlgorithm()
    {
        arValues = new ArrayList();     
    }
}

public class Example
{
    LargestNumAlgorithm theAlgorithm = new LargestSumAlgorithm();
    theAlgorithm.AddValueToArray(1);
    theAlgorithm.AddValueToArray(2);
    theAlgorithm.AddValueToArray(3);
    theAlgorithm.AddValueToArray(4);
    theAlgorithm.AddValueToArray(5);

    int iResult = theAlgorithm.ComputeMaxSum(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, use std::nth_element() to partition the array into two sets, one of them containing the N largest elements (unordered). Selection algo runs in O(n) time.

Comment: The asker is looking for better approaches to the problem.  "Use C++" isn't a real answer, especially considering he didn't tag his question with C++.