# Most efficient way to display top 100 integers from a file containing 1 billion integers. Memory can hold at max 1 million integers

Tags: algorithm

There are 1 billion integers stored in a file. One line per integer. Memory can support loading of 1 million integers at a time. We need to display 100 largest integers.

My thoughts :

1. Use a max heap data structure of size 100.
2. Take 1st million integers from the file and put in the heap.

Comment: This is the time to learn about priority queue.

Comment: @MBo : I thought about priority queue. It is implemented in a heap data structure. I can have a max heap of the first 1 million number I read, but what next?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746648/throwing-the-fattest-people-off-of-an-overloaded-airplane/7746745#7746745 for the general idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the top 100 numbers from one hundred million of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550624/retrieving-the-top-100-numbers-from-one-hundred-million-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Build **min-heap** for the first 100 elements.

For every new element check - if it larger than heap top, remove top, insert new element.

Heap size always is 100.
So overall complexity is O(N * log(100)) = O(N)
(in common case of k top values - O(N log k))

Million is used just as max size of block that you read from file, then walk through it.

Comment: The general solution is O(n log k), which is essentially O(n) when `k` is very small in relation to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to iterate over the file once:

- Have an ordered list of top 100 integers
- Iterate over the file: If a number is big enough, put it in top 100

**Edit:** Inserting a new number into the top 100 is **O(n)** if you use a sorted list and **O(log(n))** if you use a heap. So if the performance of the process depends on the insertion it makes sense to use a heap. If it depends mostly on reading the file then it doesn't matter.

Comment: You'll end up doing 100 billion comparisons that way.  Should at least keep the structure in order so you can just compare the lowest entry.

Comment: Nah you only compare to the lowest element.

Comment: Provided it's an ordered structure, yeah.  Just wrote that in my comment.

Comment: Why you want to have an ordered list? With min heap, we can get the lowest integer in O(1). We don't need to sort the list for just keeping the track of the current lowest integer. I think @MBo's solution is more efficient.

Comment: Lowest integer is a[99]. How is that not O(1)? And you never need to sort the full list, just do every insert in the right place.

Comment: This is going to be very expensive if that "top 100" is a sorted list, because inserting into the list is O(n), where n is the number of items in the list. Sure, determining whether the item should go into the list is O(1), but then you have to iterate over the list to determine in which spot it will go.So the worst case becomes O(n * 100).

Comment: Actually inserting only takes O(log(n)) because you can do binary search. I still don't understand why a heap is better.

Comment: Ok it seems like finding the right spot to insert is O(log(n)), but actually inserting is O(n) because you have to shift all succeeding numbers. I'll edit my answer.