# cKDTree vs dsearchn

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy

I have two arrays `(A,B)` containing: `ID`, `x`, `y`, `z` of the same number of points but slightly differents.
I would like to have an array in where each row has the `ID x y z` of the two nearest points of the two arrays.
At the moment I have this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
A = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
B = np.loadtxt('B.txt')
tree = cKDTree( B[:,[1,2,3]] )
d, inds = tree.query( A[:,[1,2,3]], k=1, p=np.inf, eps=0.0)
A_new = A[inds]
xyz_near = np.hstack(( B[:,0:4], A_new[:,0:4] ))
```

But the array `xyz_near` does not contain the right couple (IDB xB yB zB DIA xA yA zA):

12587   18.0445 0.0784  -7.4705 3422    18.0444 0.0403  -7.4639

12588   18.0447 0.0783  -7.2231 3421    18.0446 0.0402  -7.2164

12589   18.0450 0.0781  -6.9756 7764    18.0461 0.0400  -5.9785

12590   18.0452 0.0779  -6.7281 7765    18.0464 0.0399  -5.7310

12591   18.0454 0.0777  -6.4805 7766    18.0467 0.0399  -5.4835

12592   18.0457 0.0775  -6.2329 7767    18.0470 0.0398  -5.2359

12593   18.0459 0.0773  -5.9852 7768    18.0473 0.0398  -4.9884

As you can see the first two rows are right but not the next.

If I do the same thing in matlab with `dsearchn` (IDB xB yB zB DIA xA yA zA):

12587   18.0445 0.0784  -7.4705 3422    18.0444 0.0403  -7.4639

12588   18.0447 0.0783  -7.2231 3421    18.0446 0.0402  -7.2164

12589   18.0450 0.0781  -6.9756 3420    18.0448 0.0402  -6.9688

12590   18.0452 0.0779  -6.7281 3419    18.0450 0.0401  -6.7212

12591   18.0454 0.0777  -6.4805 3418    18.0453 0.0401  -6.4737

12592   18.0457 0.0775  -6.2329 3417    18.0455 0.0400  -6.2261

12593   18.0459 0.0773  -5.9852 3416    18.0458 0.0400  -5.9785

that is right.
I have tried to change `p` to 1, 2 and `np.inf` but this gives the same result.

Files:

A.txt: http://pasted.co/8c5b6156

B.txt: http://pasted.co/28a228e6

Thanks

UPDATE:
Even with the fix suggested by ergo_ I got:

12587   18.0445 0.0784  -7.4705 7758    18.0448 0.0403  -7.4639

12587   18.0445 0.0784  -7.4705 3422    18.0444 0.0403  -7.4639

12588   18.0447 0.0783  -7.2231 3421    18.0446 0.0402  -7.2164

12588   18.0447 0.0783  -7.2231 7759    18.0450 0.0402  -7.2163

12589   18.0450 0.0781  -6.9756 7760    18.0452 0.0402  -6.9688

12589   18.0450 0.0781  -6.9756 3420    18.0448 0.0402  -6.9688

12590   18.0452 0.0779  -6.7281 3419    18.0450 0.0401  -6.7212

12590   18.0452 0.0779  -6.7281 7761    18.0454 0.0401  -6.7212

12591   18.0454 0.0777  -6.4805 7762    18.0456 0.0401  -6.4736

12591   18.0454 0.0777  -6.4805 3418    18.0453 0.0401  -6.4737

So it considers multiple times the same points.

Comment: Copypaste from #scipy channel: `<ergo_> instead of A_new = A[inds] you should be doing B_new = B[inds]`

Comment: Thanks to you and ergo_. Seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunally even with B_new = B[inds] I have problems see the update.

Comment: The answer you get is "for each point in A, which point in B is the closest", which naturally does not necessary list all points in B. If you want to ask the converse question, interchange A and B.

Comment: But I don't undestand why with 'dsearchn' I don't get this problem. Even if I swap A and B not I get multiple references for A.

Comment: Using nearest_neighbors_kd_tree from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363419/finding-nearest-items-across-two-lists-arrays-in-python/15366296#15366296 seems to work.

Comment: Very unclear at this point now what (i) your new Python code is, and (ii) what your Matlab code is, (iii) what do you actually want to do. Do you expect there to be 1-to-1 mapping? dsearchn does not guarantee that either, maybe you used different p-norm? `nearest_neighbors_kd_tree` answers a different question.

Comment: Basically I am doing the same thing with python and matlab. The plots that I get after this research of the nearest have more sense with matlab than with python. That's why I think that matlab is the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify cKDTree gives the correct results.
Here, for the question "for each point in A, which point in B is the closest":

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
A = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
B = np.loadtxt('B.txt')
tree = cKDTree( B[:,[1,2,3]] )
d, inds = tree.query( A[:,[1,2,3]], k=1, p=2)
B_new = B[inds]
xyz_near = np.hstack(( B_new[:,0:4], A[:,0:4] ))

for j, a in enumerate(A):
    # compute 2-norms from each point in B to a
    dd = np.sqrt(((a[1:] - B[:,1:])**2).sum(axis=1))
    # find closest point
    jx = np.argmin(dd)
    # check solution
    assert inds[j] == jx
    assert np.allclose(d[j], dd.min())
    # check it is unique
    assert (dd[jx+1:] > d[j]).all()
    assert (dd[:jx] > d[j]).all()

print("All OK")
```

The solution is also unique, as shown above.

If on the other hand you want 1-to-1 mapping, which is a different question, that is given in
[finding nearest items across two lists/arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363419/finding-nearest-items-across-two-lists-arrays-in-python/15366296#15366296)
However, I do not think `dsearchn` gives you this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dsearchn` of Octave or Matlab without triangulation could be lead into this lines of numpy / python code:

```
def dsearchn(x,y):
"""
Implement Octave / Matlab dsearchn without triangulation
:param x: Search Points in
:param y: Were points are stored
:return: indices of points of x which have minimal distance to points of y
"""
IDX = []
for line in range(y.shape[0]):
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(x - y[line, :], 2), axis=1))
    found_min_dist_ind = (np.min(distances, axis=0) == distances)
    length = found_min_dist_ind.shape[0]
    IDX.append(np.array(range(length))[found_min_dist_ind][0])
return np.array(IDX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It produces the same result as the MATLAB method "dsearchn(P,T,PQ)" with triangulation.

```
# xy=[[x1,y1]...[xm,ym]]
# XY=[[X1,Y1]...[Xm,Ym]]

tree = cKDTree(xy[:, 1:])
dd, ii = tree.query(XY, k=2, p=2, eps=0.0)
Z = []
for i in range(len(dd)):
    min_dd = min(dd[i])
    min_dd_idx = np.where(dd[i] == min_dd)[0]
    if len(min_dd_idx) > 1:
        sorted_ii = np.sort(ii[i][min_dd_idx])
        Z.append(sorted_ii[len(min_dd_idx) - 1])
    else:
        Z.append(ii[i][0])
```