# dict_key and dict_value to list performances

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictview

With python 2.x we can do this:

```
>>> d = {0:'foo', 1:'bar'}
>>> d.keys()
[0, 1]
>>> d.keys()[0]
0
>>> d.values()
['foo', 'bar']
>>> d.values()[0]
'foo'
```

With python 3.x, `.keys()` return *dict_key* and `.values()` return *dict_value*. I guess these *view objects* are most performant than direct list render in python 2.x (like generator ?).

But, to access dict key/dict value by index we have to use list():

```
>>> d = {0:'foo', 1:'bar'}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys([0, 1])
>>> d.values()
dict_values(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> list(d.values())[0]
'foo'
>>> list(d.keys())[0]
0
```

Is there a way to access them by index (0, 1, [...] 999] without make a complete `list()` of keys/values to access one index ? (I work with very big dictionnary)

**This question is about performance. Not about how to do it. Duplicate flag is not pertinant.**

Comment: `next(iter(d))` or `next(iter(d.values()))`.

Comment: you can convert to an iterator then use `next` , `>>> next(iter(d.keys()))
0`

Comment: Those view objects exist because they provide a “view” to the dictionary’s internal representation of the keys and values. So if the dictionary internally uses something other than lists (which is the case), then you don’t have the overhead of having to create an in-memory list of all the keys/values.

Comment: My question is about access an index, not only '0'. @poke: thx !

Comment: If you need to access the dictionary at multiple indexes, then store the indexes in a (sorted) list, and enumerate through the views. Then, when you hit an index you care for, stop and do the stuff with the value.

Comment: @poke i see i can gain or lose perf: http://pastebin.com/PT28xqRS maybe i can determine where is the middle.

Comment: Why do you want to access a dictionary by index? This is normally not the way, how you work with dictionaries.

Comment: @poke (seems to be most perf when index is under 10%. http://pastebin.com/0xVTya0Q )

Comment: @Daniel Hi, it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28760992/801924

Comment: @bux: so the answer is, use numpy arrays instead of dictionaries. You don't need to store your information twice.

Comment: @Daniel i see a little what you say. So, in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28760992/801924 , how to store "pheromones" in numpy array, and do the same goal that this answer ?