# KD Tree gives different results to brute force method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I have an array of 1000 random 3D points & I am interested in the closest 10 points to any given point. [In essence the same as this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486093/millions-of-3d-points-how-to-find-the-10-of-them-closest-to-a-given-point)

I checked the 2 solutions offered by J.F. Sebastian, namely a brute force approach & a KD Tree approach.

Although both give me the same indices for the closest points, they give different results for the distances

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

a = 100 * np.random.rand(1000,3)
point = a[np.random.randint(0, 1001)] # point chosen at random

# KD Tree
tree = KDTree(a, leafsize=a.shape[0]+1)
dist_kd, ndx_kd = tree.query([point], k=10)

# Brute force
distances = ((a-point)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
ndx = distances.argsort() # indirect sort 
ndx_brt = ndx[:10]
dist_brt = distances[ndx[:10]]

# Output
print 'KD Tree:'
print ndx_kd
print dist_kd
print
print 'Brute force:'
print ndx_brt
print dist_brt
```

My output,

> KD Tree: 
>   [[838 860 595 684 554 396 793 197 652 330]] 
>   [[  0.   3.00931208   8.30596471   9.47709122  10.98784209
>      11.39555636  11.89088764  12.01566931  12.551557    12.77700426]]
>
> Brute force: 
>   [838 860 595 684 554 396 793 197 652 330]
>   [   0.   9.05595922   68.9890498    89.81525793  120.73267386
>     129.8587047   141.3932089   144.37630888  157.54158301  163.25183793]

So what is the issue here? Am I calculating the distance wrong?

Comment: sqrt(163.25183793) = 12.77700426

Comment: oh yeah duhh. If you put it as an answer I'll give you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KDTree` algorithm is computing the nearest points based on the square-root of the same distance used by `Brute-force` algorithm.

Basically KDtree uses: `sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)` 
and Brute-force algorithm uses: `x^2+y^2+z^2`

Answer (score 0):

distances = ((a-point)**2).sum(axis=1) **0.5[image]